# Channel tag showing future entries but show_future_entries is not set to yes

Tags: channel-entries, time

I have an entry showing a start time of 1:00pm today (current local time is 10:04am CST). The server time using php date is showing the same as our current local time.

This is my channel entries tag:

> {exp:channel:entries channel="general" category="4|14" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="2"}

If I change the entry date to tomorrow, it doesn't show up. But when I change it to today's date with a future time, it shows up.

Now I've just taken a look at the template on the Sync Templates page and it says it was last saved at 4:00pm (I just saved it at 10:09am).

My php ini file says the timezone is America/Chicago for both Local and Master Value.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

**Updated:**

I will check on SSH access. It's on Enginehosting but my set up doc is not accessible at the moment.

The entry was set for 1:00pm when it was created at 10:00am because we didn't want it to show up until the afternoon.

The Localization settings have not been changed at all (except when we first set the site up last year).

The user and I were logged in with the same username/pass.

Comment: one more clue - when I look at the same template file in my FTP client, it says it was updated at the local time, not 4:00pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin, Localization Settings. Check that Server Time Zone is correct there and that the DST setting is correct.

**Update:** Within your `exp:channel:entries` output, compare `{entry_date}` to `{current_time}` to see if those match your expectations. See [Current Time](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-time).

> ah yeah, there's a clue - the current_time says 4:37pm while entry_date is 1:00pm. So does that sound like the server time is off and I need to add an offset to the Localization Settings?

What sort of server do you have? Do you know where the host is located? Trying to figure out how best to validate:

> The server time using php date is showing the same as our current local time.

Is it a server you have SSH access to?

Did you change localization settings after the entry was created? I'm not sure that would trigger an update of the entry's date values. What happens if you edit the entry again? The offset may be stored in the actual entry as well.

Also -- Does the user who created the entry have a different time zone set? I've had that bite me before too.

This stuff is a pain in EE.

Comment: oh yeah, forgot to add that - both of those settings are correct.

Comment: Are you outputting the `entry_date` within Channel Entries to verify it matches your expectations?

Comment: And what if you compare `{entry_date}` to `{current_time}`? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#current-time

Comment: ah yeah, there's a clue - the current_time says 4:37pm while entry_date is 1:00pm. So does that sound like the server time is off and I need to add an offset to the Localization Settings?

Comment: Updated with a few other questions to try to figure out the actual server date and whether the entry's date is correct.

Comment: Another update: User's have their own time zone settings too.

Comment: yes! That was it! It was set to Greenwich Mean. Thank you so much for sticking with me on this one!